# Solution check for $z^2 + |z|^2 = 2+ 2i$ where $z^2=t$

Tags: complex-numbers

I solved this equation,

$$z^2 + |z|^2 = 2+ 2i$$

placing $z^2=t$

at the end remains:

$$\begin{align}
t&=(2+2i)/2 \\
t&=1+i \\
z^2&=i+1 \\
(z+1)(z-1)&=i \\
z_1&=1+i \\
z_2&=-1+i 
\end{align}$$

I checked with Wolfram|Alpha, but the result are:

$z=-1-i$

$z=1+i$

could you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: you must improve your question and what is x ?

Comment: I was wrong to write, was z not x

Comment: actually everything is wrong . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basically that, for complex numbers $z$, $z^2 \neq \left|z\right|^2$ in general.

Write out $z = x + iy$, then the equation is

$$
(x + iy)^2 + (x + iy)(x-iy) = 2 + 2i\\
x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy + x^2 + y^2 = 2 + 2i \\
2 x^2 + 2xyi = 2 + 2i
$$

Now you know the real part of the left hand side has to be equal to the real part of the right hand side, and similarly for the imaginary parts. Use this to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: thx, but when I put a system{x=+-1;xy=1 the final result is the real part(+-1) and the imaginary part(+-i) so +-1+-i, includes 4 solutions(1+i;-1+i;1-i;-1-i) which I have to take?

Comment: If you first choose $x = 1$, then $2xy = 2y = 2$ and you don't have any choice about what $y$ is. Similarly, if $x = -1$, there is only one $y$ that is a solution. Thus, there are only two answers, not four.